# Wrong result in Stemming in aws cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, stemming

Could you please help to find solution in search.
When I put input somethig like this (Actual):

> **"oncology*"  in search, result is "oncology", "oncolytic"**
>
> **"oncolo*"  in search, result is "oncology"**
>
> ---
>
> **"oncolytic*", result is "oncology"**
>
> **"oncolyti*", result is ""**
>
> **"oncolyt*", result is ""**
>
> **"oncoly*", result is ""**
>
> **"oncol*", result is "oncology", "oncolytic"**

But i need result like (Expected):

> **"oncol*", result is "oncology","oncolytic" and etc**
>
> **"oncolo*", result is "oncology"**
>   etc ...
>
> **"oncoly*", result is "oncolytic"**
>   etc ...

in scheme I use stemming dictionary, and algorithmic stemming set to 'none'.

I tried set algorithmic stemming to "minimal", "light", "full" too.

Result is same, (actual).